# Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, node.js

I am using react as my font end, and nodejs as backend which is running on localhost:3016 and I used nginx as reverse proxy and load balancer;
this my nginx conf file for the site

````
upstream load_balance{
    #least_conn;
     #ip_hash;
    server  localhost:3016;
    #server localhost:8010;
    #server localhost:8011;
    #server localhost:8012;
    #server localhost:8013;
    #server localhost:8014;
    #server localhost:8015;
    #server localhost:8016;
    #server localhost:8017;
    #server localhost:8018;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ethiolive.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ethiolive.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    #root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ethiolive.net www.ethiolive.net;
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin,x-auth' always;
        #default_type application/json;
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass  http://load_balance;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
         }
    }
        location / {
        root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend/users/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        }
    location /admin {
        root /var/www/html/LiveStream/LiveStream-frontend/admin/build;      index index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /socket/ {
                proxy_pass http://load_balance/socket.io/;
        proxy_redirect          off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }               
        location /socket.io/{
        
                proxy_pass http://load_balance/socket.io/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
               
    }
           ```
I get this error
````

2.2664eafa.chunk.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ethiolive.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://192.168.8.101:3016/catagorey/getMainCategorie'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.```
from chromes console,
I think I am missing something on the nginx configuration, thanks

Comment: Configure your nodejs to generate the pages with the correct HTTPS urls.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem, and I believe sharing the solution would be helpful for others, use this 'proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
below is how I configured

```
location /api {
                proxy_pass http://load_balance;
                proxy_http_version  1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host  $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
                proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

hope you find it helpful!